# How can I prevent Pygame from getting events between two while loops?

Tags: python, while-loop, raspberry-pi, pygame

I have been trying to create a sprinter game on the Raspberry Pi but the user can cheat by hitting the arrow keys during the countdown. How can I stop the key events from being collected outside of the actual sprinting piece? I am guessing I need to add something in the "while distance < 64: loop. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import pygame
import time
from time import sleep
from sense_hat import SenseHat

sense = SenseHat()


pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((140,180))

high_score = 50
name = "no-one"
foot = 1 #only lets you start with your left foot

red = (80, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 80)
gameStart = False
while True:
    print ("READY!")
    sleep(1)
    print("SET!")
    sleep(2)
    print("GO!")
    events = 0     
    distance = int(0)
    start_time = time.time()


    #sets the distance of the race (64) pixels

    while distance < 64:

        #Getting the Key input
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and foot == 1:
                    print("left")
                    foot += 1
                    distance += 1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and foot == 2:
                    print("right")
                    foot -= 1
                    distance += 1
        if distance == 32:
                print("Halfway There!")

        #Makes the pixels red if distance is less than the pixel number
        pixels = [blue if i < distance else red for i in range(64)]
        sense.set_pixels(pixels)

    #subtracts your finish time by your start time    
    fin_time = time.time()-start_time

    #rounds your finish time and start time to closest 100th of a second
    fin_time = round(fin_time,2)


    print("Finish!")
    print (fin_time)


    #checks to see if your time was a high score
    if fin_time < high_score:
        print("You got a high score!")
        name = input("Please Enter your name: ")
        high_score = fin_time
        print("High Score", name, high_score)


    #gives time to prepare for next round
    sleep(5)

    print("Click back on the black pygame window")
    sleep(1)
    print("Next round in...")
    print("5")
    sleep(1)
    print("4")
    sleep(1)
    print("3")
    sleep(1)
    print("2")
    sleep(1)
    print("1")
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `pygame.event.clear()` method: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.clear. In your case, this should work:

```
...
pygame.event.clear()
while distance < 64:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        ...
```

You may also have a look at the `pygame.time` module: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you for your help, kind stranger!

Comment: If you are satisfied of one answer, do not forget to validate and upvote it by checking the corresponding buttons. Here on StackOverflow, it is like gold. Have a nice day by the way.